Fees understanding
I have a few qustions regarding fees:

Default CU price is 0, so a payer doesn't pay for used CUs?
Does a payer pay for enire CU limit, or only for
CUs actually consummed.  For example, if the CU
limit is set to 10,000 and only 300 CUs are
consumed, is the payer charged for just the 300
CUs?
How the fees of this transaction was formed
(3oxYAUBzj6taX1A3xPgmDJswBSGkv8t7pVFmqVeg9T6QK8bJydbb8Tr2CHy9VDTYkmTmG6KYmdNUid5NdXC8JDXR):

I understand that 5,000 lamports were paid for 1 signature. However, I see an
additional 10_000 lamports charged. Can you help explain where these additional lamports
come from?
I used the formula (CU price * 10^-6 * CUs consumed) to estimate the fee, which
suggested that 45 additional lamports should be paid. Could you clarify why there is a
discrepancy?




Since it's a few questions, we'll go one by one!

Correct, no fee for CUs if the price is 0
The payer pays for the requested limit. This allows validators to choose which transactions will actually make them the most fees.
Transactions are capped to 1.4 million CUs, so the fees from your transfer are:


5000 lamports for the signature
1_400_000 * 0.099999 = 139998.6 (rounds up to 139999 lamports)
0.01 SOL for the transfer amount
Which means that the account lost a total of ◎0.010144999, exactly the correct amount

